# UFW: Allow app/profile only from specific IP

Tags: ufw

I want to restrict external access to e. g. Dovecot to specific source IPs. Allowing an app profile works great at all, but the connection's source is never limited ("From: Anywhere"):

```
$ sudo ufw status

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Postfix                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Dovecot IMAP               ALLOW       Anywhere
```

But how can I restrict Dovecot IMAP to a specific source IP?

I tried:

```
$ sudo ufw allow "Dovecot IMAP" from 1.1.1.1
ERROR: Wrong number of arguments
```

So this seems not working...

Asking for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, ufw 0.36

Comment: Upvote because many tutorials and quick guides (e.g. [tutorial from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands) ) show how to allow apps and then how to restrict port numbers, which IMHO defeats the purpose of app profiles.

Answer (score 12):

### The short answer:

```
sudo ufw allow from <IP adress>/<subnet mask> to any app <profile name>
```

Remember to quote 'Dovecot IMAP', in your case.

### The long answer:

> I tried: $ sudo ufw allow "Dovecot IMAP" from 1.1.1.1

Tho that would be the most intuitive command, the syntax is a little trickier.

I don't know what *Dovecot IMAP* is, so I'll take OpenVPN as an example.

---

We want to allow an app profile trough ufw **only** if it comes from a certain IP/subnet.

Consider we have the following *ufw app profile* in /etc/ufw/applications.d/ named **openvpn** (the profile filename is important here):

```
[OpenVPN]
title=OpenVPN server
description=This rule allows connections to VPN server at <servername>.
ports=8880/udp
```

**NOTE:** We're using a customized port here for OpenVPN.

Now add the rule to ufw with:

```
 sudo ufw allow from 10.0.0.0/24 to any app openvpn
```

This will **open the port** specified in */etc/ufw/applications.d/openvpn* for incoming **connections from** 10.0.0.0/24.

And check:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

If it worked you should have an output like:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), allow (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8880/udp (OpenVPN)         ALLOW IN    10.0.0.0/24
```

---

**Be careful with the profile filename and the service name.**

```
sudo ufw allow from 10.0.0.0/24 proto udp to any port openvpn
```

This is a very similar syntax, also correct. But it applies to the service's port configuration in /etc/services , wich may not be the one you want to allow (like we changed OpenVPN port to 8880).
In this case, we still have the following in /etc/services :

```
openvpn         1194/tcp
openvpn         1194/udp
```

Ufw recognizes *openvpn* as the service, unless we say something else.

> any port openvpn (<- service)

> any app openvpn (<- app profile)

So issuing `sudo ufw allow from 10.0.0.0/24 proto udp to any port openvpn` results in:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), allow (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
1194/udp                   ALLOW IN    10.0.0.0/24
```

This way **we effectively opened a port** for OpenVPN, **but not the port we specified** in our /etc/ufw/applications.d/openvpn app profile.

Never tried but should work if you change the port in /etc/services (risking to break something else).

You can check [this Ubuntu manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ufw.8.html) for detailed info on the ufw command.

Hope it helps.